# Date Formula field help

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

Good Day,

Would like to request assistance on a formula.
I am trying to capture the Day & Month of a field called Contract_Start_Date__c and then add the year today.

For instance Contract Start Date 02/27/2018

I need to copy 02/27. and then I need to make the year Today().

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you taken a look at the [formula operators and functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) page to try to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use four functions in your formula per the [formula documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5)

**Month** - Returns the month, a number between 1 (January) and 12 (December) in number format of a given date.
*Use:* MONTH(date) and replace date with the field or expression for the date containing the month you want returned.

**Day** - Returns a day of the month in the form of a number between 1 and 31.
*Use:* DAY(date) and replace date with a date field or value such as TODAY().

**Year** - Returns the four-digit year in number format of a given date.
*Use:* YEAR(date) and replace date with the field or expression that contains the year you want returned.

**Date** - Returns a date value from year, month, and day values you enter. Salesforce displays an error on the detail page if the value of the DATE function in a formula field is an invalid date, such as February 29 in a non-leap year.

*Use:* DATE(year,month,day) and replace year with a four-digit year, month with a two-digit month, and day with a two-digit day.

Putting in all together using your example:

```
Date(Year(Today()), Month(Contract_Start_Date__c) Day(Contract_Start_Date__c))
```

When Contract_Start_Date__c is 02/27/2018 the formula above will return 02/27/2019

Comment: Legend! thanks alot